# Regex if-condition's suite not executing when true / matched

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to echo something if a regex is matched in a string in PHP.

When I do `if(true){//...}` the suite executes, but when I do `if(regex){//..}` it is not working.
By which I mean, the echo that is inside the suite is not executing.

What am I doing wrong?

Basically what I trying to do is echo something if $query looks like 2+2, 3* 5, or 4.0 / 1.2

Here is what is working:

```
<?php
if(true){
    echo "<div class=\"calc\">Mathematical Operation</div>";
}
?>
```

And here is what is not working even though it should match $query, which is 2+ 2:

```
<?php
if(preg_match('/(\d+)(\s)*([+/*-])(\s)*(\d+)/', $query)){
    echo "<div class=\"calc\">Mathematical Operation</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all of your example strings, like this one `4.0 / 1.2`, you will also need to change up how you match your digits to allow for floating point. The following regex will match "343.4" etc, which your current regular expression won't.

```
if (preg_match('/(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*([*+\/-])\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?)/',$query)){
    echo "<div class=\"calc\">Mathematical Operation</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read what the warning tells you:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '*' in php shell code on line 1
```

It means that there's going something wrong before an `*`.

In this case it's the unescaped delimiter `/` (as you can guess from the `unknown modifier`).

Use:

```
// ---------------------------v (note the backslash here to escape the delimiter)
if (preg_match('/(\d+)(\s)*([+\/*-])(\s)*(\d+)/', $query)){
    echo "<div class=\"calc\">Mathematical Operation</div>";
}
```

Comment: The other way around is changing the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex pattern:

```
/^\s*[0-9\.]+\s*[\+\-\*\/]\s*[0-9\.]+\s*$/
```

it should match the operations separately, i.e:

```
2+2
3* 5
4.0 / 1.2
```

the input should be like:

```
$query = "2+2"; //or 3* 5 etc

if(preg_match('/^\s*[0-9\.]+\s*[\+\-\*\/]\s*[0-9\.]+\s*$/', $query)){
    echo "<div class=\"calc\">Mathematical Operation</div>";
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing space, number or period, space, mathematical operator, space, number or period, and space. Shouldn't there not be spaces or \s before and after?

Comment: its a 0 or more spaces. just in case if he has spaces at the beginning of the string..